# Does the Stanford NER CRF implementation use sentences in the training phase?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am new to CRFs and some of my terminology might be skewed so bear with me. I'm assuming the Stanford NER implements a linear chain CRF.

Let x be a sequence of words and y the sequence of corresponding tags. Call x an example and y its label. A component x_i of x is a word. A component y_i of y is a tag.

1. When training the model we provide it with something like:

   ```
   James    PERSON
   lives    O
   in       O
   Chicago  LOCATION
   .        O
   Coffee   O
   in       O
   Trieste  LOCATION
   is       O
   great    O
   .        O
   ```

   Does model use individual sentences as examples? Using the data above is one of the examples: **< Coffee in Trieste is Great . >**? Does this mean that a feature functions cannot depend on words in previous sentences?
2. If this is indeed the case, how does the model make sure that each example is indeed a sentence? Does it do any sentence boundary detection? Can it be made to look at e.g. batches of 4 sentences?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two newlines are considered boundary of an example. Your examples can be anything from phrases to the whole documents. So for your example, if you want two sentences as two examples:

```
James    PERSON
lives    O
in       O
Chicago  LOCATION
.        O


Coffee   O
in       O
Trieste  LOCATION
is       O
great    O
.        O
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to splitting the text per sentence compared to using the entire document?

Comment: Depends on whether you think the NER tags you working with are more predictable if they are at start or end of sentences. For the usual NER tasks, it doesn't make a big difference -- may be 1-2% improvement in performance. However, if your sentences are not cleanly split, then it's better to go with documents as examples.